# How to clone Dynamic object in Haxe?

Tags: dynamic, clone, haxe

I have a Dynamic object from Json and need to clone that in Haxe.
Is there any easy way to clone object, please let me know.
Or if it's impossible, I want at least iterate that Dynamic object such as JavaScript object.

```
var config = {
    loop : true,
    autoplay : true,
    path : "data.txt"
};
var newConfig = {};
for (i in config) {
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(i))
        newConfig[i] = config[i];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Reflect.copy()`](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#copy):

```
var newConfig = Reflect.copy(config);
```

Note that it only guaranteed to work on [anonymous structures](https://haxe.org/manual/types-anonymous-structure.html). For other objects, use the appropriate `Reflect` methods.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your answer. By the way what type of values are not guaranteed for that? For example the data parsed from Json will works well?

Comment: Data parsed from `haxe.Json` can be null, number, string, array, or anonymous objects (same as anonymous structures in Haxe). If you are sure you're parsing an anonymous object, it is safe to use `Reflect.copy()`. Everything else is not guaranteed to work, e.g. null, number, string, array, class instances, enum instances etc.

Comment: Yes, I have tested so the result of Reflect.copy was always anonymous structure though the source object is number, string or array.
Thanks for your best solution and perfect experiences.

Answer (score 2):

```
var newConfig = Reflect.copy(config)
```